# Keeping track of data for analytics without hitting the database each visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading another SO question/answer about adding home-made analytics to a Rails application. In the answer, someone noted that you shouldn't hit the database for each view, but they didn't elaborate.

I'm adding analytics to user profiles on my site. Each time a someone visits a profile, I'm checking whether a visitor is registered and whether the visitor is viewing his own profile (no need to record that) and then I'm saving the ip, the viewer's id (if registred) and the viewer's role (my app users rolify) to the database, each time a user's profile is viewed.

I can't think of a straightforward way to avoid saving to the DB each time a profile is viewed.

Can you explain how I might do it?

The (admittedly ugly) code below is my current implementation from the show action of my users_controller.rb

```
      @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
      ip = request.ip

        if session['warden.user.user.key'][1]  #checks if visitor is registered

          visitor_id = session['warden.user.user.key'][1]  #gets the user id of the visitor 
          visitor_id = visitor_id[0]
            if @user.id != visitor_id  #don't record visits to own profile
              visitor = User.find_by_id(visitor_id)
              if visitor.has_role?(:somerole)
                visitor_role = 'lawyer'
              elsif visitor.has_role?(:someotherrole)
                visitor_role = 'student'
              elsif visitor.has_role?(:admin)
                visitor_role = 'admin'
              else
                visitor_role = 'user'
              end 
            else
                puts 'visiting own profile'
            end       

         else
          visitor_id = nil  #unregistered visitor
          visitor_role = nil  #unregistered visitor
        end
       if @user.id != visitor_id  #don't save visits to own profile 
        Profileview.create!({:viewer_role => visitor_role, :viewer_id => visitor_id, :ip => ip, :user_id => @user.id}) 
      end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's all upto you that what your requirement that will be used in future. if you want to store user data for future purpose like analysis purpose then store into db otherwise you can keep it on a session or cache base. i think there will be a purpose of analysis so you are doing right.